# React Native IosPushNotification error

Tags: reactjs, push-notification, react-native, apple-push-notifications

Hi im trying to build a push notification app with react-native. So I did everything they say in their page (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html#content). But when I copy the example at the bottom on the page and I try to run it I get the following error:

Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module. [error_img.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GB7jL.png)

Here is my index.ios.js:

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react');
var ReactNative = require('react-native');
var {
  AlertIOS,
  PushNotificationIOS,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View,
} = ReactNative;

class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight
        underlayColor={'white'}
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={this.props.onPress}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonLabel}>
          {this.props.label}
        </Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}

class NotificationExample extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    // Add listener for push notifications
    PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('notification', this._onNotification);
    // Add listener for local notifications
    PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('localNotification', this._onLocalNotification);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Remove listener for push notifications
    PushNotificationIOS.removeEventListener('notification', this._onNotification);
    // Remove listener for local notifications
    PushNotificationIOS.removeEventListener('localNotification', this._onLocalNotification);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          onPress={this._sendNotification}
          label="Send fake notification"
        />

        <Button
          onPress={this._sendLocalNotification}
          label="Send fake local notification"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _sendNotification() {
    require('RCTDeviceEventEmitter').emit('remoteNotificationReceived', {
      aps: {
        alert: 'Sample notification',
        badge: '+1',
        sound: 'default',
        category: 'REACT_NATIVE'
      },
    });
  }

  _sendLocalNotification() {
    require('RCTDeviceEventEmitter').emit('localNotificationReceived', {
      aps: {
        alert: 'Sample local notification',
        badge: '+1',
        sound: 'default',
        category: 'REACT_NATIVE'
      },
    });
  }

  _onNotification(notification) {
    AlertIOS.alert(
      'Push Notification Received',
      'Alert message: ' + notification.getMessage(),
      [{
        text: 'Dismiss',
        onPress: null,
      }]
    );
  }

  _onLocalNotification(notification){
    AlertIOS.alert(
      'Local Notification Received',
      'Alert message: ' + notification.getMessage(),
      [{
        text: 'Dismiss',
        onPress: null,
      }]
    );
  }
}

class NotificationPermissionExample extends React.Component {
  state: any;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {permissions: null};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          onPress={this._showPermissions.bind(this)}
          label="Show enabled permissions"
        />
        <Text>
          {JSON.stringify(this.state.permissions)}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  _showPermissions() {
    PushNotificationIOS.checkPermissions((permissions) => {
      this.setState({permissions});
    });
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    padding: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  buttonLabel: {
    color: 'blue',
  },
});

exports.title = 'PushNotificationIOS';
exports.description = 'Apple PushNotification and badge value';
exports.examples = [
{
  title: 'Badge Number',
  render(): ReactElement<any> {
    PushNotificationIOS.requestPermissions();

    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          onPress={() => PushNotificationIOS.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(42)}
          label="Set app's icon badge to 42"
        />
        <Button
          onPress={() => PushNotificationIOS.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(0)}
          label="Clear app's icon badge"
        />
      </View>
    );
  },
},
{
  title: 'Push Notifications',
  render(): ReactElement<any> {
    return <NotificationExample />;
  }
},
{
  title: 'Notifications Permissions',
  render(): ReactElement<any> {
    return <NotificationPermissionExample />;
  }
}];
```

Is there any way I can fix it?
Thanks.

-------------------- SOLVED --------------------

I manage to solve the problem by changing the index.ios.js with this code:

```
'use strict';
import React, { Component, } from 'react';

import {
  AlertIOS,
  PushNotificationIOS,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View,
  AppRegistry
} from 'react-native'

class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight
        underlayColor={'white'}
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={this.props.onPress}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonLabel}>
          {this.props.label}
        </Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}

class AwesomeProject extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    // Add listener for push notifications
    PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('notification', this._onNotification);
    // Add listener for local notifications
    PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('localNotification', this._onLocalNotification);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Remove listener for push notifications
    PushNotificationIOS.removeEventListener('notification', this._onNotification);
    // Remove listener for local notifications
    PushNotificationIOS.removeEventListener('localNotification', this._onLocalNotification);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          onPress={this._sendNotification}
          label="Send fake notification"
        />

        <Button
          onPress={this._sendLocalNotification}
          label="Send fake local notification"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _sendNotification() {
    require('RCTDeviceEventEmitter').emit('remoteNotificationReceived', {
      aps: {
        alert: 'Sample notification',
        badge: '+1',
        sound: 'default',
        category: 'REACT_NATIVE'
      },
    });
  }

  _sendLocalNotification() {
    require('RCTDeviceEventEmitter').emit('localNotificationReceived', {
      aps: {
        alert: 'Sample local notification',
        badge: '+1',
        sound: 'default',
        category: 'REACT_NATIVE'
      },
    });
  }

  _onNotification(notification) {
    AlertIOS.alert(
      'Push Notification Received',
      'Alert message: ' + notification.getMessage(),
      [{
        text: 'Dismiss',
        onPress: null,
      }]
    );
  }

  _onLocalNotification(notification){
    AlertIOS.alert(
      'Local Notification Received',
      'Alert message: ' + notification.getMessage(),
      [{
        text: 'Dismiss',
        onPress: null,
      }]
    );
  }
}

class NotificationPermissionExample extends React.Component {
  state: any;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {permissions: null};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          onPress={this._showPermissions.bind(this)}
          label="Show enabled permissions"
        />
        <Text>
          {JSON.stringify(this.state.permissions)}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  _showPermissions() {
    PushNotificationIOS.checkPermissions((permissions) => {
      this.setState({permissions});
    });
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    padding: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  buttonLabel: {
    color: 'blue',
  },
});

exports.title = 'PushNotificationIOS';
exports.description = 'Apple PushNotification and badge value';
exports.examples = [
{
  title: 'Badge Number',
  render(): ReactElement<any> {
    PushNotificationIOS.requestPermissions();

    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          onPress={() => PushNotificationIOS.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(42)}
          label="Set app's icon badge to 42"
        />
        <Button
          onPress={() => PushNotificationIOS.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(0)}
          label="Clear app's icon badge"
        />
      </View>
    );
  },
},
{
  title: 'Push Notifications',
  render(): ReactElement<any> {
    return <NotificationExample />;
  }
},
{
  title: 'Notifications Permissions',
  render(): ReactElement<any> {
    return <NotificationPermissionExample />;
  }
}];

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import AppRegistry.

`import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';`

Or

```
var { AlertIOS, PushNotificationIOS, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableHighlight, View, AppRegistry } = ReactNative;
```